# Copy innertext from a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard, contenteditable

I know that there is a similar question but when I try it, it doesn't work. I figured out that it's because I've changed the position of the button above the div I want to copy, but I don't know how to fix it :/ I must say I haven't understood the JS :/

```js
  function copy() {
      var target = document.getElementById('mydiv');
      var range, select;
      if (document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(target)
        select = window.getSelection();
        select.removeAllRanges();
        select.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        select.removeAllRanges();
      } else {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(target);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
      }
    }
```

```css
#mydiv{
border: solid black 1px;
border-radius: 4x;
margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="copy()" type="button" value="Copy" />
<p></p>
<div>Insert text below</div>
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `range.selectNodeContents(target)` instead of `range.selectNode(target)` to avoid copying the outerHTML as well

```js
  function copy() {
      var target = document.getElementById('mydiv');
      var range, select;
      if (document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(target)
        select = window.getSelection();
        select.removeAllRanges();
        select.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        select.removeAllRanges();
      } else {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(target);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
      }
    }
```

```css
#mydiv{
border: solid black 1px;
border-radius: 4x;
margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="copy()" type="button" value="Copy" />
<p></p>
<div>Insert text below</div>
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
```